# How to pass a Falcon session in SQLAlchemy event

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, event-handling, falconframework

I'm trying to handle sqlalchemy events in falcon, the task is to send a message when a model field is changed:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Date, ForeignKey, Numeric
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy_utils import UUIDType

from app.model import MyBaseModel

from app.emails import MyEventListener


class EventSend(MyBaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'event_send'

    event_to = Column(Numeric(5, 1), nullable=True)
    current = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)
    start = Column(Date)
    end = Column(Date)
    status_id = Column(UUIDType, ForeignKey('status.id'))


event.listen(EventSend.status_id, 'set', MyEventListener.handler, named=True)
```

In MyEventListener I would like to know the user, who made changes and triggered the event. But how can I get the authenticated user without a session passed?

`event`  sends to MyEventListener only the following arguments:

```
kwargs["value"]: new value for triggered field
kwargs["oldvalue"]: current value of the field
kwargs["target"]: object that triggers event e.g. app.model.EventSend object
kwargs["initiator"] sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.Event object
```

MyEventListener:

```
class MyEventListener(object):

    @classmethod
    def handler(cls, *args, **kwargs):

        if args:
            print(args)
        elif kwargs:
            print(kwargs)
        else:
            print("Wrong or unknown event")
```

Could you advise me, please, how I can get the user in this case? Or what should be done to get the user that has made changes when the event is triggered in the handler?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you, but isn't the Falcon handler called as a result of a REST call, say a POST operation? In that case you can treat the user as a resource, for example: /api/v1/users/{user_id}/profilepic

Comment: I mean that using `event.listen()` I can't pass user to `MyEventListener`, but how can I do that?
The flow is when `MyEventListener.handler` is called by event I need to send a message to user called it.

Comment: What I'm getting at is that your problem arises from your design (i.e., in the way your components are interacting). The fact that you are using SqlAlchemy hooks to get the information about the record that was updated shows you are doing it the wrong way. 
The Falcon handler knows that user invoked the REST call, no? So, why not just call MyEventListener from there?